# How do I simplify this regex?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

The regex is:

$$R=0^*10+0^*101+0^*10110^*$$

$$R=0^*10(\epsilon+1+110^*)$$

$$R=0^*10(\epsilon+1(\epsilon+10^*))$$

This is as far as I got and don't know how to simplify further.

If anyone was wondering, this is for finding the DFA which accepts strings that **do not contain 110**. I constructed a DFA that **did accept 110**, found its complement, and developed an expression which I am trying to simplyify

Comment: Your regexp seems to be incorrect. For instance, it does not accept strings in $1^*$.

Comment: does $+$ represent or?

Comment: please check this question (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/regular-expression-for-the-strings-without-a-particular-substring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a DFA which accepts **all strings not containing 110**, you can't just use the negation of a DFA which does accept 110. You must use the negation of the DFA which accepts **exactly those strings containing 110**. The regular expression corresponding to the DFA accepting only strings containing 110 is $(0\cup1)^*110(0\cup1)^*$.

To negate this, simply switch the accepting and non-accepting states of the DFA (**draw them!**), and figure out the resulting regular expression, which is $0^*(100^*)^*1^*$. Note that this regex expresses strings where there are any number of single ones surrounded by zeros, and then any number of ones.

Comment: I followed this exact procedure. I drew my DFA, switched the excepting and non excepting states, I just needed help on, how exactly did you convert from DFA to regex?